# Can I leave out values from the range, when I'm using Random.Next method?

Tags: random, range

I am making a password generator wich needs to make a string of upper and lower case letters givin in a random order. The max and min value is specified by two sliders.

I would like to give up two ranges (65, 90) and (97, 122) for the int variable that returns the number for the charachter, instead of using two variables with a different range.

When I use the range of (65, 122) there are characters being given that I don't want, when generating the password.

```
    private void btnPaswoord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GenereerPaswoord();
    }

    private void GenereerPaswoord()
    {
        int iMin = Convert.ToInt32(sldMin.Value);
        int iMax = Convert.ToInt32(sldMax.Value);

        txtPasw.Text = GeefPaswoord(iMin, iMax );
    }


    private string GeefPaswoord(int iMin, int iMax)
    {
        string sPaswoord ="";

        if (sldMin.Value <= sldMax.Value)
        {
        int iLengtePaswoord = moWillekeurig.Next(iMin, iMax + 1);

        for (int iTeller = 0; iTeller < iLengtePaswoord; iTeller ++ )
        {
            int iAsciiWaarde = moWillekeurig.Next(65, 123);
            char cLetter = (char)iAsciiWaarde;

            sPaswoord = sPaswoord + cLetter;
        }
            }
        else
        {
            sldMin.Value = sldMax.Value;
        }
        return sPaswoord;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the ranges are tiny, so you can generate an array of characters that contains all valid characters you might want to use in passwords and just draw from there:

```
var passwordChars =
    Enumerable.Range(65, 26)
      .Concat(Enumerable.Range(90, 26))
      .Select(Convert.ToChar).ToArray();;

var password = new string(
    Enumerable.Range(1, iLengtePaswoord)
      .Select(_ => moWillekeurig.Next(passwordChars.Length))
      .Select(x => passwordChars[x]));
```

To precisely answer your question, though, you can use so-called rejection sampling. That is, you draw random numbers until you get one that satisfies your criteria:

```
int iAsciiWaarde;
do
{
    iAsciiWaarde = moWillekeurig.Next(65, 123);
} while (iAsciiWaarde <= 90 || iAsciiWaarde >= 96);
```